# How to check if a values of list are in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list and I want to check if a porcentage of the elements of the list match in the dictionary. So first I do for any value.

I used any function but only returns one False. Later I tried this:

```
d = {'key1': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'key2': ['b', 'l'], 'key3': ['m']}
key_words = ['a', 'b', 'l']
result = [test in d.values() for test in key_words]
```

I expected to obtain [True, True, False].
But the output is [False, False, False].
I think that I don't loop into all the list.

Comment: are you using Python >=3.7?

Comment: your values of D would result in an array / iterable of arrays.   So a != [a,b,c].

Comment: @Fallenreaper - do you mean a list of lists?

Answer (score 1):

`d.values()` is giving you back `[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['b', 'l'], ['m']]`.

Note that this is not the same thing as `['a', 'b', 'c', 'l', 'm']`, and therefore `'a' in d.values()` will never be `True`.

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {'key1': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'key2': ['b', 'l'], 'key3': ['m']}
key_words = ['a', 'b', 'l']
[v in list(d.values())[i] for i, v in enumerate(key_words)]
```

---

or

```
x = zip(key_words, d.values())
[a in b for a, b in x]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the dictionary & check if any value is in your `key_words` array.

```py
d = {
    'key1': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'key2': ['b', 'l'],
    'key3': ['m']
}

key_words = ['a', 'b', 'l']

for item in d.values():
    arr = []
    for i in item:
        if i in key_words:
            arr.append(True)
        else:
            arr.append(False)
    print(arr)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I want. I have another question: how can I apply this to a DataFrame column?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do this.

```
d = {'key1': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'key2': ['b', 'l'], 'key3': ['m']}
key_words = ['a', 'b', 'l']
data = set([])
for arr in d.values():
  for i in arr:
    data.add(i)
result = [i in data for i in key_words]
```

It will create a set of options so there are no duplicates and walk that data. The set is used to keep the value count low as you are just looking to see if the character exists, not how many times it exists.